# Unable to fetch admin config form submitted values

Tags: 8, forms

I created a admin config form in drupal 8 . I am not able to fetch the saved values using this code.

```
namespace Drupal\courier_quote\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\ConfigFormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class AlterableVariables extends ConfigFormBase {

  protected function getEditableConfigNames() {
    return [
      'courier_quote.settings',
    ];
  }

  public function getFormId() {
    return 'altvariables';
  }

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $config = $this->config('courier_quote.settings');

    $form['Price_per_mile'] = [
      '#type'          => 'textfield',
      '#title'         => $this->t('Price Per Mile'),
      '#default_value' => $config->get('Price_per_mile'),
    ];
    $form['minimum_del_dist'] = [
      '#type'          => 'textfield',
      '#title'         => $this->t('Minimum Delivery Distance'),
      '#default_value' => $config->get('minimum_del_dist'),
    ];
    $form['long_dis_min_percent'] = [
      '#type'          => 'textfield',
      '#title'         => $this->t('Long Distance Minimum Percentage'),
      '#default_value' => $config->get('long_dis_min_percent'),
    ];
    $form['business_hrs_start_time'] = [
      '#type'          => 'textfield',
      '#title'         => $this->t('Business Hours Start Time'),
      '#default_value' => $config->get('business_hrs_start_time'),
    ];
    $form['business_hrs_end_time'] = [
      '#type'          => 'textfield',
      '#title'         => $this->t('Business Hours End Time'),
      '#default_value' => $config->get('business_hrs_end_time'),
    ];
    $form['after_hr_surcharge'] = [
      '#type'          => 'textfield',
      '#title'         => $this->t('After-Hours Surcharge'),
      '#default_value' => $config->get('after_hr_surcharge'),
    ];
    $form['weight_surcharge'] = [
      '#type'          => 'textfield',
      '#title'         => $this->t('Weight Surcharge'),
      '#default_value' => $config->get('weight_surcharge'),
    ];
    $form['admin_email'] = [
      '#type'          => 'email',
      '#title'         => $config->get('admin_email'),
      '#default_value' => $config->get('admin_email'),
    ];

    return parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
  }


  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $config = $this->config('courier_quote.settings');
    $config->set('courier_quote.Price_per_mile', $form_state->getValue('Price_per_mile'));
    $config->save();
    return parent::submitForm($form, $form_state);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need submit form for save data

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $values = $form_state->getValues();
  $this->config('courier_quote.settings')
      ->set('courier_quote.Price_per_mile', $values['Price_per_mile'])
      ->save();
}
```

You need replace

```
$form['Price_per_mile'] = [
      '#type'          => 'textfield',
      '#title'         => $this->t('Price Per Mile'),
      '#default_value' => $config->get('Price_per_mile'),
    ];
```

to

```
$form['Price_per_mile'] = [
      '#type'          => 'textfield',
      '#title'         => $this->t('Price Per Mile'),
      '#default_value' => $config->get('courier_quote.Price_per_mile'),
    ];
```

It's not right with your key config

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82958/discussion-on-answer-by-vinhdv-how-to-fetch-admin-config-form-saved-values).

Comment: $values is undefined in this answer

Answer (score 0):

In you submit function, you shouldn't `return the parent::submitForm` function but execute it in the beginning.
Also, you load the configuration object using `$this->config('courier_quote.settings')` then you access the keys directly without the dot e.g. `->set('price_per_mile', SOME_VALUE)`
Finally, you should use snake_case in naming the configuration keys